# Removing objects from scene in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I have a scene in andEngine. The scene has basically three animated objects. I want to add and remove means show and hide on the screen. Hows that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that I don't own an Android phone, and I have never used this API.

I think you'd need to add and remove sprites to the scene-graph:

- Removing: http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/SpriteRemoveExample.java

Example code:

```
scene.detachChild(childSpriteVariable);
```

- Adding: http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/SpriteExample.java

Example code:

```
final Sprite face = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mFaceTextureRegion);
scene.attachChild(face);
```

I'm basically getting this information by browsing this site.  It seems to be the only official docs this engine has:

http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/

Comment: remember to detachChild in UpdateThread, otherwise it may cause problems, as described in SpriteRemoveExample link

Comment: @Ludevik: If you want to edit my answer, go ahead.  I am *not* an expert on this subject ;)  Or of course you could add your own.

Answer (score 0):

To remove an object from a scene: (in this case a Sprite object but you can remove any entity)

```
 scene.getTopLayer().removeEntity(sprite);
```

To hide a scene:

```
scene.back();
```

Comment: the above method didnt worked. because gettoplayer() function is no more available in scene. :(